# Method Calls (static to non-static) for SQL and ListActivity

Tags: android, sqlite

I've read a ton of posts across the net and see many others want to do the same thing and all posts refer to needing to do something like a Singleton or use cumbersome conext routines. Why is accessing a Database wrapper class more difficult than accessing any other activity (which is pretty simple)?  I have no problem with accessing other activities from another activity - I must have been napping during that class - what am I missing?

Here's the background:

Maincode calls up a main layout with One Button.

**The Button** calls a DB Wapper class (called DB_Interface, which has a layout with buttons to do the DB things I want.  The main DB stuff is defined in the helper - I'm calling it DBHelp_mate).

Without using the Maincode, I can run the app (using the DB_Interface as the primary activity) *and it works just fine*.  **But**, as soon as I use the Maincode to call DB_Interface, it crashes when pressing the button.

Yes - I have properly changed the Manifest file to reflect which Activity is the main one as well as declaring the other activities (it's not rocket science - and, truly, I am a rocket scientist!).

**So, my question is this:** how can I call DB_Interface from Maincode and have it call up the DBHelp_mate and work?

Thanks - the new codes are a follows (sans the stuff inside the DBHelp_mate that shouldn't affect your guidance).  Please provide specific calls/code rather than saying things like "you need to instantiate. this and that" - that just makes for more confusion and many replies/re-posts.

**NEW CODE:**

```
public class Maincode extends Activity { 
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button goToDB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    //  ---------------------------------------------------------
    goToDB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent doIt = new Intent();
        doIt.setClassName("com.bt.hopex", "com.bt.hopex.DB_Interface");
        startActivity(doIt);
      }
    }); // end -----------------------------------------------   
  }//end onCreate 
}//end activity
```

**DB_INTERFACE**

```
  public class DB_Interface extends Activity { 
  private DBHelp_mate ddbb;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.db_dialog);       
        ddbb = new DBHelp_mate(this);
        ddbb.open();       
    }//end onCreate
}//end activity
```

**DBHelp-mate**

```
public class DBHelp_mate {

  private DatabaseHelper dbHelper ;
  private SQLiteDatabase db;

  private Context mCtx = null;

  //*******************************************************
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "XgAlert_db";
  private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tblData";
  private static final int    DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
      "create table gAlert_alerts ( "
      + "_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
      + "alert_text text not null,"
      + "alert_date varchar(20) not null,"
      + "alert_time varchar(20) not null"
      +");";

   //-------------------------------------------------------------
  private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context ctx) {
      super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
      db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS "+ DATABASE_TABLE); change drop to alter later after all is working!
      onCreate(db);
    }
  }

  public DBHelp_mate(Context ctx) {
    mCtx = ctx;
  }
  //********************************************************

  public DBHelp_mate open () throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
  }
  //------------------------------------------------------------
  /** Closes a database connection */
  public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
  }    
  //------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is OptPanel the name of your class or the name of a variable that contains an object of a specific type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

After many days of struggling with this, I bought a book - Android for Dummies and, ***Bingo***, the how to do it buried in the book. For those interested in how to do it, read the relevant sections of the book.

Answer (score 2):

> Given I can't change the non-static method to static, how can I call this method from another activity?

You don't. You refactor your code such that your data model is accessible from all activities that need it.

Comment: Thanks - In eclipse, there are several refactor menu item and I don't know which one to use (I suppose I could spend hours doing the homework but, well, this is a good place to start!).  Which refactor item do I use to accomplish the goal?  Thank you...

Comment: I tried the extract interface but, still doesn't work. I think the issue is this: The db cursor is intrinsically non-static and doesn't seem to like anything in the way of calls from static.  Maybe, I'm wrong... and when I change to extracted interface to static, well, it goes south too...

Comment: @headscratch: Your data model is a database (perhaps fronted by a content provider). All activities need to have access to the database. You pass `Intent` extras from activity to activity to indicate what should be retrieved from the database, just like a Web app passes GET parameters to indicate what should be retrieved from the database. You should need zero `static` anythings to accomplish this end. For example, each activity can work with a `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass to access the database.

Comment: @CommonsWare:  Thanks. I added the relevant code (above) that shows implementation of the Interface. Still not working. In the code, you'll see GetAndShow from the DB_Usable interface. These three calls cause CRASH (collectively or just one).  So, I'm either not clear on exactly what interface to extract and/or how to implement it (although, I have no problem working with java and have hand coded interfaces before - this time I used the eclipse extract feature). Thanks for hanging in with this!  I appreciate it very much.

Comment: As I sit here mulling this over, it dawned on me to ask: Are you suggesting the Methods for the database (like get records, show records...) should be in the dbHelper and not in a different class? I currently have them defined in the OptPanel class.

Comment: @headscratch: Bingo. If `OptPanel` is an activity, your database access logic should be somewhere else, so you can get to that logic from more than one activity. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/11-Database/LunchList for an example.

Comment: Thanks - I'll spend a good bit of time redoing all the code and follow up a bit later with the status.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to create an instance of the class OptPanel, like

```
OptPanel myOptPanel = new OptPanel();
```

Only in that way you are able to access the method showRecords() and give the myOptPanel as parameter to another activity (like the constructor).

```
public class MyActivity
{
    private OptPanel _optPanel;

    public MyActivity(OptPanel myOptPanel)
    {
        this._optPanel = myOptPanel;
    }

    public void showRecordsInActivity()
    {
        this._optPanel.showRecords(null);
    }
}
```

If you write

```
MyClass.myStaticClassMethod();
```

you can only access static members.

If you write

```
MyClass theClass = new MyClass();
theClass.MyObjectMethod();
```

you can access object members.

This is common OOP syntax.

Comment: `OptPanel` is an activity ("that calls Activity 'OptPanel', with it's own layout"). You never create an activity instance yourself in Android via the constructor this way.

Comment: Thanks - actually, I tried it earlier on.  But, it doesn't work and I think it's because of the cursor (the actual signature has cursor as an argument and I'm sending in 'null'.

Comment: @CommonsWave: maybe. i only wanted to explain what the problem is. i don't know the code. i only saw that the method showRecords(null) that is non-static and was tried to call in a static context.